# Why does Storm return 'ImportError: No module named os'?

Tags: apache-storm

I ran WordCountTopology example with Storm 0.8.2 but I am thrown an error as below:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "storm-0.8.2/bin/storm", line 3, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
```

Looks like the error is not from the code but Storm environment. Any suggestions where I could look into would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you running storm on?

Comment: CentOS (a linux flavor). My suspicion is that it is to do with Python's os module. I tried to import os in Python and this is what I was thrown: `>>> import os
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the script in your question that is complaining locally, its a python script. You need the python os module for this to work.

I'm not sure why its not included already can you check and see of you have it installed.

Comment: I'm writing my code in Java and have downloaded Strom as needed. I'm not sure why Python has to do anything with it.

Comment: Check the script you included in your question notice the #!/usr/bin/python at the top its a python script.

Comment: I suspect your python install is screwy can you verify its installed correctly.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not noticing what you're trying to say. Let me share what I did. I wrote a word counting topology in Java and tried to run as `storm-0.8.2/bin/storm -jar /home/jeo/storm.jar /home/joe/words.txt` for which I was thrown `'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "storm-0.8.2/bin/storm", line 3, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os` I've not written any Python script.

Comment: Oh okay, let me check with that and try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: file `"storm-0.8.2/bin/storm"` is a python script, I would try to reinstall python

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but it is Storm, not Strom.